# How to Check For Dark Mode in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Now that [iOS 13](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface) and [Android Q](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme) allow the user to enable Dark Mode at the operating system level, how can I check for it in Xamarin.Forms?

I've created this in my Xamarin.Forms project, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the values from Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

#### IEnvironment.cs

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public interface IEnvironment
    {
        Theme GetOperatingSystemTheme();
        Task<Theme> GetOperatingSystemThemeAsync();
    }

    public enum Theme { Light, Dark }
}
```

#### App.cs

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public App : Application
    {
        // ...

        protected override async void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();

            Theme theme = DependencyService.Get<IEnvironment>().GetOperatingSystemTheme();

            SetTheme(theme);
        }

        protected override async void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            Theme theme = DependencyService.Get<IEnvironment>().GetOperatingSystemTheme();

            SetTheme(theme);
        }

        void SetTheme(Theme theme)
        {
            //Handle Light Theme & Dark Theme
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use the Xamarin.Forms dependency service to access the platform-specific code from iOS and Android.

I've gone into more depth here in this blog post:
https://codetraveler.io/2019/09/10/check-for-dark-mode-in-xamarin-forms/

### Xamarin.Forms Code

#### IEnvironment

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public interface IEnvironment
    {
        Theme GetOperatingSystemTheme();
        Task<Theme> GetOperatingSystemThemeAsync();
    }

    public enum Theme { Light, Dark }
}
```

### App.cs

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public App : Application
    {
        // ...

        protected override async void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();

            Theme theme = DependencyService.Get<IEnvironment>().GetOperatingSystemTheme();

            SetTheme(theme);
        }

        protected override async void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            Theme theme = DependencyService.Get<IEnvironment>().GetOperatingSystemTheme();

            SetTheme(theme);
        }

        void SetTheme(Theme theme)
        {
            //Handle Light Theme & Dark Theme
        }
    }
}
```

### Xamarin.iOS

```cs
using System;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MyNamespace;
using MyNamespace.iOS;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Environment_iOS))]
namespace MyNamespace.iOS
{
    public class Environment_iOS : IEnvironment
    { 
        public Theme GetOperatingSystemTheme()
        {
            //Ensure the current device is running 12.0 or higher, because `TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle` was introduced in iOS 12.0
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(12, 0))
            {
                var currentUIViewController = GetVisibleViewController();

                var userInterfaceStyle = currentUIViewController.TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle;

                switch (userInterfaceStyle)
                {
                    case UIUserInterfaceStyle.Light:
                        return Theme.Light;
                    case UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark:
                        return Theme.Dark;
                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException($"UIUserInterfaceStyle {userInterfaceStyle} not supported");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Theme.Light;
            }
        }

        // UIApplication.SharedApplication can only be referenced by the Main Thread, so we'll use Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync which was introduced in Xamarin.Forms v4.2.0
        public async Task<Theme> GetOperatingSystemThemeAsync() =>
            Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(GetOperatingSystemTheme);

        static UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
        {
            UIViewController viewController = null;

            var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;

            if (window.WindowLevel == UIWindowLevel.Normal)
                viewController = window.RootViewController;

            if (viewController is null)
            {
                window = UIApplication.SharedApplication
                    .Windows
                    .OrderByDescending(w => w.WindowLevel)
                    .FirstOrDefault(w => w.RootViewController != null && w.WindowLevel == UIWindowLevel.Normal);

                if (window is null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find current view controller.");

                viewController = window.RootViewController;
            }

            while (viewController.PresentedViewController != null)
                viewController = viewController.PresentedViewController;

            return viewController;
        }
    }
}
```

### Xamarin.Android

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
using Xamarin.Forms;

using MyNamespace;
using MyNamespace.Android;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Environment_Android))]
namespace MyNamespace.Android
{
    public class Environment_Android : IEnvironment
    {
        public Task<Theme> GetOperatingSystemThemeAsync()  =>
            Task.FromResult(GetOperatingSystemTheme());

        public Theme GetOperatingSystemTheme()
        {
            //Ensure the device is running Android Froyo or higher because UIMode was added in Android Froyo, API 8.0
            if(Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Froyo)
            {
                var uiModeFlags = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext.Resources.Configuration.UiMode & UiMode.NightMask;

                switch(uiModelFlags)
                {
                    case UiMode.NightYes:
                        return Theme.Dark;

                    case UiMode.NightNo:
                        return Theme.Light;

                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException($"UiMode {uiModelFlags} not supported");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Theme.Light;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer ,which will help more people :)

Comment: Can this be done without using CrossCurrentActivity?

Comment: @stephan14x Yes - Plugin.CurrentActivity is an open-source and you can reference its implementation:  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin

Comment: @BrandonMinnick thanks, i had some issues and suspected the reason was CrossCurrentActivity, but it was something different.

Comment: After attempting this and troubleshooting the results, the iOS code doesn't work correctly as I can't have await-ables in the App()  which is needed to get the coloring correct when navigating. The OnStart() doesn't seem to work correctly: whatever the default is in your app, that will flash when navigation occurs. In other words, a default white background will flash before the page is rendered to dark mode. Setting the defaults before the page is called (i.e. SomePage()) gives the correct results. BUT iOS doesn't work and crashes because it's not returning the results. suggestions?

Comment: Also, there's alot of typos and errors that your other [site](https://codetraveler.io/2019/09/11/check-for-dark-mode-in-xamarin-forms/) doesn't have.

Comment: @Jakar510 The White flash is a bug in Xamarin.Forms: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8073

Comment: Good to know, but it happens in BOTH Android and iOS.

Comment: @Jakar510 This sample app shows how to do the same implementation without async/await: https://github.com/brminnick/gittrends

Comment: Using [this code](https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends/blob/master/GitTrends.iOS/Services/Environment_iOS.cs) i got a "System.NullReferenceException
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object". at the line "   UIViewController rootController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
"

Comment: @Jakar510 If you open a new question and send me the link, I’m happy to take a look

Comment: @BrandonMinnick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738368/normal-and-dark-mode-implementation-on-both-android-and-ios-without-the-flashes

Answer (score 16):

### UPDATE as of April 2020:

It is no longer necessary to use platform-specific services to check for light/dark mode in Xamarin.Forms.

We can now get the current theme directly via:

```
OSAppTheme currentTheme = Application.Current.RequestedTheme;
```

where the `RequestedTheme` property returns an `OSAppTheme` enumeration member: `Unspecified`, `Dark`, or `Light`.

For more info: see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes) and the [updated Xamarin.Forms Application.cs code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Application.cs).

Comment: And in XAML, there is the the great AppThemeBinding available to define UI values for dark and light theme. Used in Styles, it is a powerful tool. [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/app-themes-xamarin-forms/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/app-themes-xamarin-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS:

```
if (UITraitCollection.CurrentTraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark)
{ ... }
```