# Normal and Dark Mode implementation on both Android and iOS without the flashes using Xamarin.Forms 4.3.0.947036

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

After some discussion on the [Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879523/how-to-check-for-dark-mode-in-xamarin-forms), we needed to open a new question for its answer due to an issue found with **iOS**.

---

**The Problem:**

After attempting this and troubleshooting the results, the **iOS** [async code](https://codetraveler.io/2019/09/11/check-for-dark-mode-in-xamarin-forms/) doesn't work correctly. While **Android** works ok, the code below in `App()` doesn't seem to work correctly for **iOS**, as I apparently can't have **await**-ables in the `App()` which is needed to get the coloring correct when navigating.

```
Theme theme = await DependencyService.Get<IEnvironment>().GetOperatingSystemTheme();
```

even when using `_ = GetOperatingSystemTheme().ConfigureAwait(true);` in the `App()` the code isn't called, and therefore the Theme isn't set:

```cs
public static async Task<Theme> GetOperatingSystemThemeAsync()
{
    Theme systemTheme = await DependencyService.Get<IEnvironment>().GetOperatingSystemTheme().ConfigureAwait(true);

    SetTheme(systemTheme);
    return systemTheme;

}
```

**And the Issue when trying to use it for iOS:**

Using this [non-async Environment_iOS code](https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends/blob/master/GitTrends.iOS/Services/Environment_iOS.cs) and [the SetTheme() at Line 53 of the App.cs](https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends/blob/master/GitTrends/App.cs) I got a

> System.NullReferenceException Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object". at the line "UIViewController rootController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

If you don't call it in `App()` and instead in only in `App.OnStart()`, this [flashing issue occurs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8073).

**Troubleshooting Results:**

Whatever the default is in your app, that will flash when navigation occurs, In other words, a default white background will flash before the page is rendered to dark mode. Setting the defaults (whatever colors for the background needed. i.e. `App.Current.Resources = new DarkModeTheme()` for dark pages) before the page is called (i.e. `SomePage()`) gives the correct results as it must be done before navigation occurs and the page is rendered.

Example Repository: https://github.com/Jakar510/FlickerTest

Comment: @Julipan Thanks. Forgot about those formatting options.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the code from App.cs?

Comment: @BrandonMinnick updated; however, the Example Repository not tested currently for iOS. will test tomorrow as I don't have access to the Mac at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

`UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow` is null because Xamarin.Forms hasn't yet generated it.

### Solution

Move the call to `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow` from the constructor of `Xamarin.Forms.Application` to `Xamarin.Forms.Application.OnStart()`.

I also sent you a PR which implements this fix and also correctly implements MergedDictionaries for your Light Theme and Dark Theme: https://github.com/Jakar510/FlickerTest/pull/1

Comment: It works as expected for iOS. To remove the flashes on Android, however, additional was needed. **if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
   {
    Theme systemThemeAsync = GetOperatingSystemThemeAsync().Result;
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage(systemThemeAsync));
   }
   else
   {
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
   }**

Comment: Thanks @Jakar510! Can you add this comment to the Xamarin.Forms GitHub Issue too? Now that you know the fix, it’ll help the team and save some time troubleshooting it. 